# Dealing with MacBook Pro fan noise during audio production sessions

Tags: sound, noise

While working, i find it very disturbing to have the constant hissing of the MacBook Pro next to my ear.

How do other people deal with the noise? Since i can't really go far from the MacBook with my other equipment, due to cable lengths.

Is there something out there that can ease this? Encasing? Soundproof box?

Comment: What about trying some noise cancelling headphones?

Answer (score 2):

The pros deal with this by getting longer cables.

The problem with a soundproof box is that usually a soundproof box is also insulating to heat and more or less airtight, and you're hearing the fan because your laptop is running hot. Another option is to try to do the minimum processing possible on the laptop so the processor cools off and the fan quiets down.

You could also turn up your speakers. I wouldn't recommend headphones and certainly not noise-canceling ones because headphones are not very accurate monitors and noise-cancellation electronics work by altering the sound, so they are even less accurate.

Comment: This 'pro' deals with it by not using laptops for desktop scenarios ;-) I use Mac Pros which are essentially silent unless pushed far harder than any DAW will push them. They also have more cores, higher clock speeds & more drive space... win/win. In the old days you would get more noise from the Studer than you do from a Mac Pro.